# My laptop hangs when my battery charge drains to 10%

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery

My laptop (Dell Precision M4700) running with Windows 8.1 hangs when the battery charge drains to 10%, so I have to turn off my laptop by pushing the power button.

After restarting it still hangs as long as the battery charge is at a low level like 7% or 10%. What is wrong with my laptop?

Comment: Get a new battery.

Comment: Does the laptop hang (doesn;t do anything at all anymore), or does the battery stop charging?

Comment: @Hennes No , the laptop hangs (doesn't do anything at all anymore)

Comment: @Tetsujin Buying new battery make this issue solved ? its not related to any other hardware or OS ?

Comment: You have a machine that is 8 years old. Dead battery would be the first suspect.

Comment: @Tetsujin Haha yeah you right , So when the battery level reach to 11% Thats works like charm and i've never seen any issue ! Thanks

Comment: @Hennes Would you answer please ?

Comment: I got no answer. I suspected that your battery was not charging. As I guess did @tesujin, but if that is not the case then I simply do not have enough information for a diagnosis and solution.

Comment: Have you [checked the battery health?](http://www.dell.com/support/article/en/en/debsdt1/sln143156/checking-battery-health-status-on-dell-laptops-and-notebooks) because I concur with Hennes and Tetsujin.

Comment: @Fabby My battery is definitely alive. There is some problem with Graphic driver when i get help from technical center in tehran , They told me disable MMC/SD driver from storage section in device manager window . It was fantastic and worked for me.

Comment: I'm not saying it's currently dead: I'm saying it's dying... Did you [check the battery health?](http://www.dell.com/support/article/en/en/debsdt1/sln143156/checking-battery-health-status-on-dell-laptops-and-notebooks).  What are the results? Please [edit] your question to provide more relevant info.

Comment: @Fabby **I checked up also , its NORMAL ** Question edited.

Comment: Could you please type the solution as an answer instead of editing the question?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 Already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The problem was related to MMC/SD driver that was not installed completely. After asking the technical center they told me to disable that driver (Device Manager > Storage). So I did and then my problem was solved.